# Multiple Docker container access to host database in docker compose

Tags: database, docker, docker-compose

I have been researching how to connect multiple docker containers in the same compose file to a database (MySQL/MariaDB) on the local host.  Currently, the database is containerized for development but production requires a separate database. Eventually, the database will be deployed to AWS or Azure.

There are lots of similar questions on SO, but none that seem to address this particular situation.

Given the existing docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
 db:
  build:
   image: mariadb:10.3
  volumes:
   - "~/data/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:Z"

 api:
  image: t-api:latest
  depends_on:
   - db

 web:
  image: t-web:latest

 scan:
  image: t-scan:latest

 proxy:
  build:
    context: . 
    dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile
    image: t-proxy
  depends_on:
    - web
  ports:
    - 80:80
```

All these services are reversed proxied behind nginx, with both **api** and **scan** services requiring access to the database.  There are other services requiring database access not shown for simpliticy.

The production compose file would be:

```
version: '3.1'

 api:
  image: t-api:latest
  depends_on:
   - db

 web:
  image: t-web:latest

 scan:
  image: t-scan:latest

 proxy:
  build:
    context: . 
    dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile
    image: t-proxy
  depends_on:
    - web
  ports:
    - 80:80
```

If there was a single container requiring database access, I could just open up the ports `3306:3306`, which won't work for multiple containers.

Splitting up the containers breaks the reverse proxy and add's complexity to deployment and management. I've tried extra_hosts

```
extra_hosts:
  - myhost: xx.xx.xx.xx
```

but this generate EAI_AGAIN DNS errors, which is strange because you can ping the host from inside containers.  I realize this may not be possible

Comment: How does the `api` container know where its database is?  Configuring this using an environment variable would simplify your immediate issue.

Comment: In development, environment variable points to 'db' service. Removed db service from docker-compose and set the environment variable to IP address of host.  I am now getting a new error EHOSTUNREACH which is a no route to host error.  I'm beginning to wonder if this isn't some type of mysql driver issue.

Comment: Did you find answer for this question?

Comment: @kong No I never really found an answer